# Derterministic Route Calculation for the length of Route (HERE Routing API v8)

Tags: routes, distance, here-api

I am trying to implement a calculation of the distance between to Geopoints in VBA.
Therefor I am using the HERE Routing API v8.

So far evrything works. But i want to know if it is possible to get a determenistic distance between two point by ignoring the current traffic and road restricitions like construction sites, road closures etc. ?

So if i would calculate the distance today, then the result would be the same if i calculate it a month later.

Answer (score 1):

Routing API tries always to return optimized calculated route by calculating any penalties on the road. Penalties could be: quality of road, functional class of road, how many turns and what is angle of turns, how to difficult intersections, etc... Therefore road penalties cold be changed time by time and a calculated length of road will be changed as well.

You can only disable traffic by calculation to utilize the departureTime=any parameter then will be also ignored traffic speed limits and under construction roads but road closures will be never ignored.

You can play with route calculation on this playground: https://demo.routing.ext.here.com/